# Jenkins gitlab merge request trigger builds branch commit instead of merge commit

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

We have the usual trunk, staging, production branches, and recently had to add a hotfix to them.

The hotfix branch was created from the production branch, one commit was added, and then it was merged back into the trunk and staging branches by seperate merge requests in gitlab.

The odd thing is that when our jenkins job to deploy our staging branch got triggered by the accepted merge request, it appears to have built from the hotfix commit rather than the merge commit created by merging the hotfix branch back into staging

Our triggers for the job are 'push events, 'accepted merge request events', and 'comments' ('jenkins please retry a build')

Jenkins shows that first of all a job was run triggered by a push event, which correctly saw the merge commit and built from it, 
then another job was run which shows the same merge commit id, then shows the commit id from the hotfix branch, and then appears to choose the hotfix branch to build from instead of the more recent merge commit.